# How to log events of db2 from client(remote) requests in local machine using java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, db2

I am using java for developing this feature. In my case i have to listen events(insert,update,delete,select) in one machine where java code is present. Db2 is present in cloud. Requests(insertion,deletion etc) to db2 will come from client which is from different places.

Now i have to capture events done to db2 by clients. To make it clear i have 3 places , the one my java code resides(its in my machine) second db2 location n 3rd client which trigger db2 operations.

My question is how can i log events done to db2 by clients. I am using JPA.(not hibernate or any impl) its java's n my jdk is 1.7.

Comment: JPA has event listeners ...

Comment: Jpa listener will listen events when transaction is happen via jpa code which we can create in java with provided annotations. Here in my case i have to listen to the events made to db2 done externally. Say some one manually  opened db2 console remotly nd updated a record i should capture that event using java and jpa.

Comment: so the answer is nothing to do with JPA then, and only to do with what monitoring DB2 allows.